# Node js Calls limited number of functions in infinite loop looking for a new task

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I am looking for advice or a ready package. I have a function that encodes audio and video. But before this function is called, another function check database if there is any file to encode. My problem is I do not really know how I should implement it. My first idea looks like this

```js
let runningEncode = 0;
function runWorkFlow(maxEncode) {
      while (runningEncode < maxEncode) {
        console.log("Check if file")
        if("File"){
          ++numRunning
          console.log("start encoding")
          await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 20000)) //Encode simulation
          console.log("end encoding")
          --numRunning;
        }
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000)) //Check database for every 5 sec
      }
  }
  runWorkFlow(2)
```

But it looks terrible even for me

What I want to achieve is to call only 2 encoding functions, when one is done check the databases. If there are no files to encode, check the database every 5 seconds